# Fubini for Principal Value integrals in probability

Tags: probability, probability-theory, characteristic-functions

Take a random variable $X$ with distribution function $F(x)=\mathbb{P}[X\leq x]$ and characteristic function $\phi_X(t)$.
Then one can write

$\int_{-c}^{c}\frac{1-e^{-ixt}}{it}\phi_X(t)dt=\int_{-c}^{c}\frac{1-e^{-ixt}}{it}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{itu}dF(u)dt=\int_{-c}^{c} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{\sin tu-\sin t(u-x)}{t}dF(u)dt$

Now, according to Kendall(v1,ed5,p121) **a change of integration order** can be performed.

$\int_{-c}^{c} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{\sin tu-\sin t(u-x)}{t}dF(u)dt= \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\int_{-c}^{c}\frac{\sin tu-\sin t(u-x)}{t}dtdF(u)$

The motivation they give is that because  $\int_{-c}^{c}\frac{1-e^{-ixt}}{it}\phi_X(t)dt$ is uniformaly convergent such an operation is permitted.

**Questions**

**1.** Do they imply that Fubini theorem is used?

**2** If so, what type of integrals are the integrals wrt to $dt$ and wrt $dF(u)$ ?  The $dF(u)$ integral needs to be Lebesgue, but the integral  wrt $dt$ **?can not?** be Lebesgue since $\int^{c}_{-c} \frac{\sin x}{x} dx$ is not Lebesgue  integrable.

**3** If the two integrals are of different type how would one use Fubini?

**4** If Fubini is not used then how is the change of integration  order justified?

Answer (score 1):

$\frac{\sin tu-\sin t(u-x)}{t}$ has a removable singularity at $t=0$, that is
$ \lim_{t\to 0} \frac{\sin tu-\sin t(u-x)}{t} $ exists and is finite.  So no principle value integral is required.  It is a double integral of a bounded function over two finite measure spaces, and so Fubini applies.

Comment: But, are they Lebesgue  or Riemann integrals?

Comment: I would go with Lebesgue.  But why does it matter?

Comment: Well, it can not be Lebegue since $\int_{-c}^{c} \frac{\sin tu}{u}du$ is not Lebesgue integrable, that is $\int_{-c}^{c}| \frac{\sin tu}{u}|du \to \infty$.

Comment: But, in the same time $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{itu}dF(u)$ needs to be Lebesgue integral. So, because we have to exchange two different type of integrals how is Fubini justified?

Comment: Isn't $c$ finite?

Comment: If you want to let $c \to \infty$, which you can, then you need to use the Lebesgue dominated convergence theorem.  But doing it right at the end, you do everything with Lebesgue integrals.  And only when you are done do you then call them Riemann integrals.

Comment: Yes, $c$ is a constant and yes I need to take the limit.  So, basically because $c$ is a constant  the Lebesgue integral is defined. As a result I can see both integrals as Lebesgue, and apply Fubini as usual. Only after that I take the limit. Ok, Thanks.  But why do they say that the Fubini is justified by the uniform convergence of $\int_{-c}^{c}\frac{1-e^{-ixt}}{u}\phi_X(t)dt$?

Comment: Maybe they are justifying why the Lebesgue dominated theorem can be used.